# Online JS / CSS / HTML minifier

Tags: javascript, html, css, compression, minify

Is there a service out there that provides public API for compressing CSS or Javascript?

(Like imgur let's you upload images trough PHP and get the image URL)

Comment: Why would you want this?

Comment: because the generated css / js is dynamic, and I was thinking I could use a service like this to generate a minifed cache of the css/js

Comment: SO is actually about coding help and support, not about searching for services, there are plenty of [sites](http://google.com) that can help you with that.

Comment: How often does it change? Every page load? When you upload changed files?

Comment: when the site administrator changes the site configuration (like changing color scheme, adding new content blocks etc)

Comment: Then your approach is acceptable, though I'd personally prefer to use a minifier hosted on the site itself, as opposed to an external service.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Google Closure Compiler](http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-ref.html) let's you send JavaScript code with POST request and returns optimalized code.

Answer (score 2):

The [Closure Compiler](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home) can be used for JavaScript. It has an API (link on the top right hand corner). It does a decent job on compiling JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

The YUI compressor by Yahoo is your best bet. You can download it (http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/), or use an online solution: http://www.refresh-sf.com/yui/

It does CSS and JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty Diff can minify CSS, JavaScript, and HTML.

http://prettydiff.com/?m=minify&html

Answer (score 1):

Free developer tools can minify and beautify CSS and JavaScript.

http://freedevelopertools.com

Answer (score 1):

I prefer using the tool on [www.blimptontech.com](http://www.blimptontech.com) for minifying my Javascript files. They also have a feature to combine your files into one and minify at the same time. I like it because it uses UglifyJS to get the dirty work done.

Answer (score 1):

Another online tool you can use to minify/compressing your js is http://samqode.com/minifyjs . very soon There will be a public API available for on the fly (via url request) minification so its a good one to watch out for.

Comment: this one is based on Google Closure Compiler as well

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jsCompressor](http://javascriptcompress.herokuapp.com/) and [CSSCompressor](http://javascriptcompress.herokuapp.com/css/) for minifing your javascript and css code.

Answer (score 0):

I am using [.Maui](https://dotmaui.com) and it is awesome! You can minify and combine CSS and JS using the web tool or the free API. For JS it even optimize the code and is ES5 and ES6 compatible! There are other useful tools like Sitemap Generator, HTML Minify, Image Resizer and Free CDN for the minified files.

Before i tried [Google Closure Compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-ref?csw=1), [cssminifier.com](https://cssminifier.com/) and [javascript-minifier.com](https://javascript-minifier.com/), but they have restrict limits of POST size and number of requests per second.